# How to filter one observable stream using another stream's element attribute as criteria using RxJava?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

I'm working with two repositories with flatten data structure, ex. "MenuItemRepo" and "IngredientRepo". The relationship structure between them is: one MenuItem can contain many Ingredients, and a single Ingredient (ex. Cheese) can be part of many MenuItems. Database tables are modeled like below:

- MenuItem Table Entry

  - string MenuItem-id
  - string name ...
- MenuItem-Ingredient Reference Table Entry

  - string MenuItem-id
  - string Ingredient-id
- Ingredient Table Entry

  - string Ingredient-id
  - bool isGlutenFree ...

**Can I use RxJava to only select MenuItem elements from the [MenuItem stream] where their MenuItem ids that matches a particular Ingredient id in the [MenuItem-Ingredient reference stream]?**

I use the .filter() operator to select element base on its own attribute, in one Flowable stream (ex. get all ingredients that are gluten free):

```
mIngredientsRepo.getItems()
                .flatMap(Flowable::fromIterable)
                .filter(ingredient-> ingredient.isGlutenFree)
                .toList() ....
```

This is to get a list of all glutenFree ingredients. But MenuItem stream in this case doesn't store the ingredient ids. Essentially I want to see if SQL-like JOIN filtering is possible, and if it would remain elegant with RxJava.

Currently I've implemented on the repository level with SQLite join statements. I would like to explore more intuitive and maintainable options in RxJava.

PS: This data structure is used for both local and remote, and is also used in Firebase, that's one of the reason why the structure is flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `collect()` those ingredient Ids into a `HashSet`, then in the menuitem stream, use `filter()` with `contains` check:

```
mIngredientsRepo.getItems()
.flatMapIterable(v -> v)
.collect(HashSet::new, (a, b) -> a.add(b.id))
.flatMapPublisher(set -> menuitems.filter(mi -> set.contains(mi.id))
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but it doesn't seem to resolve the method .flatMapFlowable, my getItems() returns a Flowable<List<Ingredient>> and I'm using rxjava 2, if that's an issue.

Comment: Updated the example.